# How to access DataContext class instance created in XAML in codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

**`MyData`** is a class simply storing a **`ColorName`** property.

In XAML I can create an instance for my XAML datacontext by

```
<c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource">
```

Now,

**How do I access and change the ColorName stored in this instance of MyData (which was created in XAML with "myDataSource" key) in my code behind?**

I hope the question is clear. I 'd like to change the color programmatically. How do I get hold of the MyData class instance ? Thank you

```
<DockPanel
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource"/>
  </DockPanel.Resources>
  <DockPanel.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}"/>
  </DockPanel.DataContext>
  <Button Background="{Binding Path=ColorName}"
          Width="150" Height="30">I am bound to be RED!</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Please consider [my opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16991850/643085) on this.

Comment: @HighCore certainly interesting +1d blindly---however given my current competency level, not in a position to comment either way :p Im sure I'll have an opinion 211 apples later

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To access a resource from code-behind, give the `DockPanel` a name and then:

```
var resource = dockPanel.Resources["myDataSource"];
```

Alternatively, you can get its DataContext:

```
var dataContext = dockPanel.DataContext as MyData
```

Comment: Your 'Alternative' is Superlative

Comment: I'm doing something similar:
I say the following in the event handler of the button that is trying to read the text from textBox
```var dataContext = myWindow.DataContext as myClass;``` and then using it as ```System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dataContext.Text);```, but ```dataContext``` stays null. What might be the problem?