# Trying to access DataContext class from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, two-way-binding

I'm following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495937/how-to-access-datacontext-class-instance-created-in-xaml-in-codebehind) on how to access your `DataContext` class from code-behind. Implemeting it the way it says doiesn't work for me (apparently I'm doing something wrong).

What I'm trying to do:

I have a button that is trying to read a `Text` property from a class that is binded to `TextBox`:

```
        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            var dataContext = myWindow.DataContext as myClass;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dataContext.Text);
        }
```

For some reason `dataContext` is always null.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        x:Name="myWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:myClass x:Key="myDataSource"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="myDataSource"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="myButton_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //var dataContext = myWindow.DataContext as myClass;
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataContext = myWindow.DataContext as myClass;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dataContext.Text);
        }
    }

    public class myClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { 
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The full code is also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72719915/simple-wpf-app-with-two-way-binding-textbox-and-button-showing-message-from-tex) (that was closed since it was "answered" in the question linked above, but the solution still doesn't work for me). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="myDataSource"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

binds the DataContext to the string `"myDataSource"`. It should instead be

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

You do however not have to declare the DataContext object as resource at all. Just write

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:myClass/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

---

Also be aware that your conclusion that the "DataContext is always null" is incorrect. It is the result of the expression `DataContext as myClass` which was null, because DataContext did not contain an object of type `myClass`. In general, when you use the `as` operator, you should always check the result for `null` before accessing it. Or use the `is` operator like

```
if (DataContext is myClass dataContext)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataContext.Text);
}
```

You may also notice that using the `myWindow` field was redundant, since the code behind methods belong to the MainWindow class.